# Loop Through jQuery Function Inifitly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery Animation which I want to loop infinitely, I have the current code but it just returns nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var i = 0;
        document.write(i);

        function runTest(){
            $('#page_effect').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
            $('#page_effect2').delay(7000).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
            $('#page_effect3').delay(13900).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
            $('#page_effect4').delay(21000).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
            i++;
            runTest();
        }

       if(i === 0){
        runTest();
       }


     });
```

Many Thanks! :)

Comment: can't use `document.write` after page has loaded...will wipe out the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap them all in a function and re-call the function after the last animation has finished:

```
function run(){

      $('#page_effect').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500); 
      $('#page_effect2').delay(7000).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);             
      $('#page_effect3').delay(13900).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);             
      $('#page_effect4').delay(21000).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500,run);
}

run();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/nCs6N/

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't chain animations like this, use callbacks:

```
$("#page_effect").fadeIn(1500, function() { 
    $(this).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
});
```

This will wait for 3500ms to fadeOut, but only after the 1500ms fadeIn is complete.
This way using callbacks, you can call the function again from the last callback:

```
function runTest(){

    ...

    $('#page_effect4').delay(21000).fadeIn(1500, function() {
         $(this).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500, function() {
              runTest();
              // this will be called only after the fadeout completes
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: what are you on about?  The jQuery animation functions are specifically designed to be chained like that.  The bit that's kinda broken is that he's starting the animation on the next element with no guarantee that the previous one finished.

Comment: Looking at the code and the delays getting bigger and bigger (up to 21000) with every fade I'm assuming that these are supposed to happen in succession, so a better way would be to use callbacks. It's much more efficient to control a string of animations that way, that calculate delays in your head. The notation I used was primarily aimed to introduce callbacks and show how they work in a friendly way :)

Comment: It's completely unclear from your answer that you were talking about the delays between each of the animations on the four elements.  You've ended up with a garbled mess of chained and non-chained calls.

Answer (score 0):

You're queueing the animations, but never "yielding" execution back to the browser, because you just call the function again immediately.

The browser never gets to enter its event loop, and the animations won't start.

To fix this, you'll need to make the browser wait until all of the animations have completed, and *then* queue them again:

```
$(function() {

     (function animate() {
          $('#page_effect').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
          $('#page_effect2').delay(7000).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
          $('#page_effect3').delay(13900).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
          $('#page_effect4').delay(21000).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);

          // using deferred objects, ask for a promise that will be resolved
          // when all animations on the specified elements have been completed,
          // and when done, call myself to start all over again
          $('#page_effect,#page_effect2,#page_effect3,#page_effect4')
              .promise().done(animate);

     })();   // invoke immediately
});
```

I note that your four separate effects are *probably* supposed to run in series, but the `.promise()` based solution above will also work if they were all running in parallel.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ZKevs/

Note that if you are intending to run those effects in series you shouldn't really just queue them up all together - there's no timing guarantee and it's possible that the next element might start animation before the previous one finished.

The traditional solution to this was to add an "animation complete" callback in the last animation, but with four separate animations as you have here that would end up being horribly nested.

jQuery deferred objects can help here, too - note how this eliminates the additional calculated `.delay()` calls:

```
$('#page_effect').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);

$('#page_effect').promise().done(function() {
    $('#page_effect2').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
});

$('#page_effect2').promise().done(function() {
    $('#page_effect3').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
});

$('#page_effect4').promise().done(function() {
    $('#page_effect4').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
});

$('#page_effect4').promise.done(animate);
```

At which point you can see that every animation chain is identical and can be refactored:

```
function cycle($els) {
    var i = 0, n = $els.length;
    (function next() {
        var $this = $els.eq(i);
        i = (i + 1) % n;
        $this.fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500).promise().done(next);
    })();
});

cycle($('#page_effect,#page_effect2,#page_effect3,#page_effect4'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't call runTest() recursively like that, you'll exhaust the function stack.

Instead use `setTimeout(runTest, 0);`